# SSIS Ole DB Destination not writing

Tags: sql-server, oledb, ssis-2012

When doing a search, I see countless examples of this problem but no generic solutions.

I have a package that retrieves data from websites, puts those files on a local drive, then is supposed to post the records to a SQL Server table. First steps are all working. 15781 records are being read in from a .csv file. But 0 records are being written out. (I currently don't care about error rows so that should be irrelevant.) Here is the output of the data flow portion of the package:

> SSIS package "...\Package.dtsx" starting.
>
> Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation
>   phase is beginning.
>
> Warning: 0x80208386 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [119]: Rows
>   sent to the error output(s) will be lost. Add new data flow
>   transformations or destinations to receive error rows, or reconfigure
>   the component to stop redirecting rows to the error output(s).
>
> Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation
>   phase is beginning.
>
> Warning: 0x80208386 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [119]: Rows
>   sent to the error output(s) will be lost. Add new data flow
>   transformations or destinations to receive error rows, or reconfigure
>   the component to stop redirecting rows to the error output(s).
>
> Warning: 0x80049304 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Warning: Could
>   not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL;
>   data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run
>   this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
>
> Information: 0x40043006 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for
>   Execute phase is beginning.
>
> Information: 0x40043007 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute
>   phase is beginning.
>
> Information: 0x402090DC at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The
>   processing of file "....csv" has started.
>
> Information: 0x4004300C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Execute
>   phase is beginning.
>
> Information: 0x402090DE at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The
>   total number of data rows processed for file "....csv" is 15781.
>
> Information: 0x402090DF at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [119]:
>   The final commit for the data insertion in "OLE DB Destination" has
>   started.
>
> Information: 0x402090E0 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Destination [119]:
>   The final commit for the data insertion  in "OLE DB Destination" has
>   ended.
>
> Information: 0x40043008 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Post Execute
>   phase is beginning.
>
> Information: 0x402090DD at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [2]: The
>   processing of file "....csv" has ended.
>
> Information: 0x4004300B at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB
>   Destination" wrote 0 rows.
>
> Information: 0x40043009 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup
>   phase is beginning.
>
> SSIS package "...\Package.dtsx" finished: Success.